# Debounce not working with TinyMCE events

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I'm trying to use Ben Alman's jquery plugin debounce which will limit the times my function will get called. https://github.com/cowboy/jquery-throttle-debounce

However, saveEditor get's called each time(and many times during one keypress. The main issue is that saveEditor is getting called multiple times. I want to limit it to only be called once every delay. That's why I'm using the plugin. If anyone has a better implementation, please share.

Here is my code during TinyMCE initialization:

```
'config' => 'setup : $.debounce(1000, true, function(ed) {
      ed.onEvent.add(function(ed, e) {
      if( ((e.ctrlKey==true || e.metaKey==true)))
      {
        saveEditor(this.editorId);
        e.returnValue = false;
        e.preventDefault();
       }
      });
      ed.onClick.add(function(ed) {
            lastClickedEditor = this.editorId;
        });
   })
```

Comment: do you have several editor instances on your page?

Comment: Yes there are multiple active instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow it looks as if the save operation gets called for every editor instance on your page.
I do not know what your function call `saveEditor(this.editorId);` does (?). But it is possible to have only one editor save using `editor.save();` ([link to API](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.save)).